# Flutter: Convert address to location on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I would like to ask my users to enter their address information and display the location on a map. What is the best way ?

Comment: have you tried this library? - https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the **Geocoding API** from Google Maps, which converts an address string to latitude & longitude (and, vice-versa, known as reverse geocoding).
Using those latitude & longitude, you may set markers on the map using **Static map API** that generates a snapshot with markers based on provided latitude and longitude.
A detailed explanation on Geocoding API is mentioned here - [Geocoding API - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Also, Google Maps documentation is the best place to find out more.